# Finding the probability that $n$ points which are randomly selected from $d-1$ dimensional spherical surface are 'semi-spherical'

Tags: pr.probability, euclidean-geometry

Let $S^{d-1}=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_{d})\in {\mathbb R}^{d}|{x_1}^2+\cdots+{x_d}^2=1\}$, and let us call the intersection of any $d-1$ dimensional subset which passes through the origin and $S^{d-1}$ '**a great circle**'. Also, let us call one of two components gotten by cutting $S^{d-1}$ by a great circle '$d-1$ dimensional semi-spherical surface'. Also, suppose that a point set on $S^{d-1}$ is **semi-spherical** when it is included in a $d-1$ dimensional semi-spherical surface.

Then, here is my question.

**Question** : Letting $d\ge 2$, find the probability $f(d,n)$ that $n$ points which are randomly selected from $S^{d-1}$ are semi-spherical.

**Remark** : Suppose that $n$ points are selected randomly with equable probability.

**Example** : We can easily get $f(2,n)=n\cdot 2^{1-n}.$

**Motivation** : I've known the $d=2$ case, but I'm facing difficulty for $d$ in general. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in painstaking detail [here.](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath327/kmath327.htm)

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for great info.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not the probability that if you toss a coin n times then you get either n heads or n tails?
Paul

Comment: Nope, it is not.

Comment: I think the question is looking for the probability that the points are in some hemisphere (possibly at a funny angle), not necessarily one of two fixed hemispheres corresponding to a single great circle.